# SSH automation in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, dvc

So I've been working on the automation of processes and it includes fetching data from an external source through DVC(data version control) for which I am using SSH client to pull and push changes. For automation, I'm using **Jenkins** and the problem I'm facing is that for ssh we need to give a password on runtime, and in automation that's not an option. I've tried multiple ways to specify passwords for ssh like sshpass and ssh config but it turns out Jenkins when building creates some file name **script.sh** in a directory *repoName@tmp* in var/lib/jenkins/.... and therefore it is giving permission denied error. no matter what I try. If anyone could give any suggestions to this problem it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use key-based auth for SSH instead instead of password auth so that your Jenkins user can access your SSH DVC remote without needing to specify a password.

Comment: Just to add bit, here is one of the many links that describes the process https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-2 . And usually in all CI/CD system there is a way to save the keys into secrets and fetch then in the pipeline when it runs.

Comment: Thanks you. Your answer leaded me to a SSH plugin in jenkins to specify password.